# How to Add new Property Object in State Vuex/Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

i have a state, and i want put new property `foo: 'bar'` to `detail` state

```
export const state = () => ({
  detail: {a: 'b', c: 'd'}
})

export const mutations = {
  SET (state, data) {
    state.detail.foo = 'bar'
  }
}
```

and i show the state in html

```
<template>
  <div>{{ data}}</div>
  /* {a: 'b', c: 'd'} */
</template>
<script>
..
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      data: state => state.detail
    })
  },
..
</script>
```

the data is showing `{a: 'b', c: 'd'}`, but when i click the button to add `foo: 'bar'` the state will changed, but not refresh in html. i mush F5(refresh the browser) to show the new data `foo: 'bar'`

Comment: option1: add a watcher to the state. if the state changes because u added something, it automatically refresh it self

option2: load the state in a computed inside your component

option3: add a `:key` and update the value of the key to force a rerender 
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import vue in your store code then use `Vue.set(state.detail,"foo" , 'bar')`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
....

export const mutations = {
  SET (state, data) {
   Vue.set(state.detail,"foo" , 'bar')
  }
}
```

Comment: It's Worked, Thank You!
You know the problem I have? My code is work for changing the state, just not showing the latest data if property not there. If there have the property, it's showing the latest data. And is this a best practice for import vue in state?

Comment: Yes it's good practice in order to avoid reactivity caveats

Answer (score 1):

Use getters, they re-render on changes

```
export const state = () => ({
  detail: {a: 'b', c: 'd'}
})

export const mutations = {
  SET (state, data) {
    state.detail.foo = 'bar'
  }
}

export const getters = {
   detail: (state) => state.detail 
}
```

And in your template

```
<template>
  <div>{{ data}}</div>
  /* {a: 'b', c: 'd'} */
</template>
<script>
..
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      data: "detail"
    })
  },
..
</script>
```

dont forget to import it correct

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"
```

Comment: Thank You for the explanation!
I have try it, but not work. The @Boussadjra Brahim answer it's work..

Comment: no, no errors. I use your code before, and result like my issue. Then trying code Boussadjra Brahim and keep your code (i use getters to get data, not state like before).